# In cross_val_score, how is the parameter cv being used differently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm trying to figure how to do k-fold cross validation. I was hoping someone could tell me the difference between my two print statements. They give me largely different data and I thought they would be the same.

```
##train is my training data, 
##target is my target, my binary class.

dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
kf = KFold(n_splits=10)
print(cross_val_score(dtc, train, target, cv=kf, scoring='accuracy'))
print(cross_val_score(dtc, train, target, cv=10, scoring='accuracy'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DecisionTreeClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) derives from [`ClassifierMixin`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.ClassifierMixin.html#sklearn.base.ClassifierMixin), and so as mentioned in the docs (*emphasis mine*):

[**Computing cross-validated metrics**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation)

> When the `cv` argument is an integer, `cross_val_score` uses the [`KFold`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold) or [`StratifiedKFold`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold) strategies by default, **the latter being used if the estimator derives from `ClassifierMixin`**.

So here when you are passing `cv=10` you are using the `StratifiedKFold` strategy, whereas when passing `cv=kf` you are using the regular `KFold` strategy.

In classification, stratification generally attempts to ensure that each test fold has approximately equal class representation. See [Understanding stratified cross-validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/understanding-stratified-cross-validation) on Cross-Validated for some more info.